# Unable to get response from aws api gateway?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed my api on aws amazon api gateway and If I go through resource and make a request to an endpoint, I am able to get the response however when I go to stages and invoke url with params and x-api-key then I don't get any response with warning 'Unexpected 'N'' and 'Not Acceptable'. How is it possible that output is changed after deploying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong, for all the post request body needs to be sent as form-data, when I changed body from form-urlencoded to form-data, I got the response...Thats very naive of me.